# Function with multiple parameters in swift

Tags: swift, function, parameters, arguments

I need to define and call a function called `areaOfRectangle` that takes two `Int` parameters, `length`, and `width`, and prints the result of `length * width`.  I actually got result with `length * width` but it is telling me to make sure I’m defining a function with the correct name and parameters. The answer below will print `length * width` which is right but the steps are not what it should be.

```
func areaOfRectangle(length: Int, width: Int) {

    print(“length * width”)

}

areaOfRectangle(length: 0, width: 0)
```

Comment: Look under [Printing constants and Variables](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the function correctly but made a small mistake in the front statement as it will always print **length * width** in the output console as its a string not the operator or operands. Here is the solution

```
func areaOfRectangle(length: Int, width: Int) {

    print("\(length * width)")

}

areaOfRectangle(length: 0, width: 0)
```

just added **'\'()** in the print statement

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way you can `return` string result from `Int` parameters:

```
//define a return type as String here
func areaOfRectangle(length: Int, width: Int) -> String {
    print("\(length * width)")  //same thing you can print here 
    return "\(length * width)"  //return it as String
}

let result = areaOfRectangle(length: 5, width: 5)
print(result) //"25"
```

Comment: I'd like to print "length * width" so the answer is right but the steps are not correct.

Comment: what you mean by `print` can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

```
print(“length * width”)
```

in this statement length and width are being treated as string literals. Any thing that comes between "" is a string literal at least in swift, also in some other languages.

Swift provide a very good syntactic sugar to use variables and constants within the string by putting the `vars` and `lets` within `\()`. Hence when you correct the above statement to `print(“\(length * width)”)`. It will print correct result of length*width.

Updated code:

```
func areaOfRectangle(length: Int, width: Int) {
    print(“\(length * width)”) //42
}
areaOfRectangle(length: 6, width: 7)
```

Answer (score -1):

Explaination:
function with multiple parameters., in which the function greet have parameter of alreadyGreeted also a condition it will check when we give argument label of person and bool is true, we call it, and function will start its execution... condition is checked,. then greetAgain function is called with its argument label... and print "hello Again" with person name that is in greet-main function calling parameter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).